# RxJs Observable - Handle 404 by emitting default value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am calling MS Graph to get a user's photo:

```
    // lets get the photo itself
    let photo$ = this.graph.get$(`users/${id}/photo/$value`, ResponseContentType.Blob)
        .map(resp => {
            return new Blob([resp.blob()], { type: resp.headers.get['Content-Type']}); })
        .map(photo => {
            let urlCreator = window.URL;
            return this.sanitizer
                .bypassSecurityTrustUrl(urlCreator.createObjectURL(photo));
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            if(e.status === 404) {
                // no photo for this user!
                console.log(`No photo for user ${id}!  Returning default...`);
                return undefined;
            }
        })
        .toPromise();
```

However many users don't have a photo.  In that case what I would like to do is create an object URL for some default photo (one of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=default%20user%20svg) perhaps) and emit that from the Observable.  Or even just emit an `undefined` from the Observable, which I can handle in the front end by displaying some default image.

I know that my catch is firing, because I see this in the browser console:

> No photo for user xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx!  Returning
>   default...  (output redacted)

I'm actually pulling in many different bits of data for each user, each in its own Observable.  I then convert each of those Observable to Promises, and then do a `Promise.all()` on all of them.

```
    // let's pull all of this together to form a ConcreteUser
    return Promise.all([photo$, ...])
        .then(values => {
            const photo = values[0];
            ...
```

The problem is in the case of a 404 for a user's photo, the whole `Promise.all` aborts, and I can't retrieve the user.

I've tried catching errors in the `photo$` observable and emitting an `undefined` (which I planned to handle later), but it doesn't seem to be doing what I want.

How do I handle 404s in my Observable here, and emit something else (perhaps `undefined`) instead of killing the observable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I may have figured this out.  A hint was lurking in the browser console...

> TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You
>   can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Reading the RxJs [documentation on error handling](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/errors.md) showed them doing what I'm trying to do, so I was a bit confused by this.  But then I noticed that in the documentation they call a mystery function `getCachedVersion()` which I assumed returned an actual cached thing.  However if they instead returned an `Observable.of()` some actual cached thing, then that might explain it.

When I changed my catch code to:

```
        .catch(function (e) {
            if(e.status === 404) {
                // no photo for this user!
                console.log(`No photo for user ${id}!  Returning default...`);
                return Observable.of(undefined);
            }
        })
```

...it all started working.

Answer (score 3):

To translate [Johns answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42751447/542251) into an up-to-date rxjs implementation, this now looks like:

```
import { Observable, throwError, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
 
const observale: Observable<unknown>; 

observale.pipe(
   catchError(err => {
       if(err.error.statusCode === 404) {
          return of(undefined);
       } else {
          //important to use the rxjs error here not the standard one
          return throwError(err);
       }
   })
)
.subscribe(val => {
      console.log('success but may be undefined');
   }, err => {
      console.log('error');
});
```